# what type of font is this? haha i really need to know!

Tags: font-identification

i want to know what kind of font this is being used on this poster. please let me know!! it’s the upper left black poster

[image]

Comment: "*Kind* of font"?? Emm.. well.... Latin san-serif.

Comment: It's probably [Kabel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabel_%28typeface%29)

Answer (score 1):

It's Kabel, with the letters squashed close together in 1970s style.